# How to print Bytes in order in a endian-portable way?

Tags: c, linux, endianness

I used this simple function extensively in a multi-threaded program:

```
char *Serial2String(char *serial) {
    static char str[LENGTH * 2 + 1];

    sprintf(str, "%08x%08x",
            ntohl(*(uint32_t *)(&serial[0])),
            ntohl(*(uint32_t *)(&serial[LENGTH / 2])));

    return str;
}
```

I call it from different thread context, and the static variable is not protected against concurrency. So a bug will happen sooner or later... I created this function to simplify the code where it is needed, but created a concurrency issue. I am looking for a way to either:

- have this function concurrent-safe. Holding a mutex would work. But would make my code uglier/heavier than it is already.
- have a macro or one-liner doing the same thing simple enough to copy/paste it everywhere I need it. Inlining works but I believe there is a *better* way.

In other words, how can I print `LENGTH` Bytes in a certain order with a portable way (from an endianness point of view) in a thread-safe way?

**EDIT** I usually call it directly in a `printf` statement:

```
printf("error: no such device, serial:%s\n", Serial2String(&buf[1]));
```

Comment: You're asking about concurrency and endianness, which seem to be two completely unrelated topics...

Comment: It being atomic would not buy you anything. Trouble is, the `static` buffer would still be shared.

Comment: couldn't you use semaphores to ensure only one thread can call this function at a time?

Comment: @Deduplicator you're right. So I'm looking for a one-liner instead of a function

Comment: I couldn't find a way better than `inlining`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see a couple of options.

Allocate the string within the function with malloc:

```
const char *str = Serial2String(serial);
// Use the string, free when you're done
free(str);
```

Alternatively, make the caller pass in memory for a string:

```
char str[256];
str = Serial2String(serial, str, 256);
```

If you use it exclusively inside a printf, you could do the following:

```
#define SERIAL_FORMAT "%08x%08x"
#define SERIAL2STR(s) ntohl(*(uint32_t *)(&s[0])), ntohl(*(uint32_t *)(&s[LENGTH / 2]))

printf("The serial is:" SERIAL_FORMAT "\n", SERIAL2STR(serial));
```

Comment: EDIT I usually call it directly from `printf()`. Having to allocate at the callee side would make it heavier than it was initially.

Comment: See my edit for a macro way to do this, if you exclusively use it with printf().